# Chrome driver not working headlessly with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am new to Selenium programming with Python. I am trying to use the switch_to.frame() and other driver functions after opening a URL. The code works fine without the `--headless` argument, but does not execute at all when I try to run it headlessly. Could someone help me out with it?
The URLs I am trying to access work via single sign-on, which happens automatically on opening the browser window. Could there be an issue with this?
I am using Python 3, Chrome browser version 62.0.3202.94, and Selenium driver version 2.31.488763.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--headless')
d = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
d.get("myURL") #cannot display the actual URL for privacy
d.switch_to.frame('MyFrame')
d.switch_to.frame('MyWorkArea')
print("Done")
d.close()
```

NOTE: On running the browser normally, the code worked fine, but on running it headlessly, I got a NoSuchFrameException.

Comment: post the code that you're using

Comment: The selenium chrome driver is independent of the chrome browser so you have to login using the selenium Chrome driver. If you already have this post the code to check it out.

Comment: I have added the code in the edit. 
Also, to get the program to run even without the headless argument, I had to downgrade my Chrome version from 63 to 62, and disable autoupdate. So are you sure about the version independence?